# Firebase AngularFire .key() method producing TypeError

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm going through the AngularFire Guide

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-basics

and when I try to run the example code

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleController", function($scope, $firebase) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
  var sync = $firebase(ref);

  sync.$set({foo: "bar"});

  sync.$push({hello: "world"}).then(function(newChildRef) {
    console.log("added record with id " + newChildRef.key());
  });
});
```

I am getting the following error in Dev Tools console

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

[image]

And if I run

`console.log(newChildRef);`

It produces the following

```
G {i: Gf, path: H, Ga: undefined, fa: undefined, za: undefined…}
  Ea: undefined
  Ga: undefined
  fa: undefined
  fb: undefined
  i: Gf
  path: Hz
  a: undefined
  __proto__: c
```

Lots of undefineds there. What is going wrong here?

Comment: change your line 7 to var - sync = $firebase(ref).$asArray()

Comment: nvm thats probably not gonna work

Comment: well right, I mean it should work just like in the guide.

Comment: You're not injecting firebase into your app/module: `var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);`. That last bit between `[` and `]` is missing in your code. Hmmm.... surprisingly, this seems to run.

Comment: In general when you get this type of error, set breakpoint on your code (by clicking on the line numbers in Sources tab) and run the code again. At the very least this will allow you to pinpoint the line where the problem occurs, so that we don't have to figure that out.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/fd1csze6/. If you need help, provide a similar fiddle - or the code that fails for you in a format that one can copy/paste into a fiddle.

Comment: I had an old version of Firebase. When I updated to 2.0.4 the problem went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out I had just had to update my Firebase to 2.0.4. to get the `.key()` method to work. Problem solved.

Comment: `key` used to be called `name` in older versions of Firebase, so if you're stuck on an old version you can use that.